# Saving an ajax datatable back to the database with php

Tags: php, jquery, database, datatables

So I'm working with datatables and where I can edit the values in the datatables. I ran into a problem with actually saving the changes, at first this method worked but when I came back the next day it just didn't want to work anymore.
   Is there anything obvious I'm missing here? Or is there something more to the story?

Server side code:

```
case 'form_save': {
    $form_id = !empty($post['form_id']) ? $post['form_id'] : false;
    $data = array();
    $where = array('id'=>$this->db->escape($post['id']));

    if(!empty($form_id)) {
        switch($form_id) {
        case 'translations': {
          $data['value'] = $this->db->escape($post['value']);
          $rc['success'] = $this->db->update('translations',$data,$where);
          break;
        }
        case 'carousel': {
          $data['title'] = $this->db->escape($post['title']);
          $data['src'] = $this->db->escape($post['src']);
          $data['alt'] = $this->db->escape($post['alt']);
          $data['slide_url'] = $this->db->escape($post['slide_url']);
          $data['slide_order'] = $this->db->escape($post['slide_order']);
          $rc['success'] = $this->db->update('carousel',$data,$where);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
```

JQuery code:

```
 $(document).on('submit','form',function(){
    var $form = $(this);
    var $error = $form.find('div.error');
    var form_id = $form.attr('id');
    var $modal = $(document).find('.modal');
    var data = $form.serializeArray();
    data.form_id = form_id;
    data.type = 'form_save';
    $.post('/admin_get/',data,function(rc){
      if(rc.success) {
        $modal.modal('hide');
        $modal.find('modal-title').html('');
        $modal.find('modal-body').html('');
      } else {
        $error.html(rc.error).show();
        $error.html('').hide();
      }
    },'json'); 
  });
});
```

EDIT: forgot to add the edit form jquery side :

```
  $(document).on("click", ".edit", function(){
var id = $(this).data('id');
var table = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
var $modal = $(document).find('.modal');
$.post('/admin_get/', {id:id, type:'get_form', table:table}, function(data){
  $modal.find('.modal-title').html(data.title);
  $modal.find('.modal-body').html(data.html);
  $modal.find('.modal-body').find('#summernote').summernote();
  $modal.find('.modal-body').find('.select2').select2();
  $modal.modal('show');
},'json');


 });
```

Comment: As always: what does "_it just didn't want to work anymore_" mean? Get a white page? AJAX not hitting the endpoint? Inserting wrong data? Anything in the logs? Or your browser console?

Comment: Extremely sorry for the vagueness, I'm really new to this, the web console doesn't put out any errors and the datatables still work, but the issue I'm having is that it isn't saving the values in the database and I've doublechecked the the data inserted .